# Orchard Dynamic Forms Workflow not invoked

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I made a simple workflow in Orchard 1.9.1 to notify when a dynamic forms is submitted.

I didn't set any prpoperty/data on the Start Activity so that it can capture all Dynamic Forms submission. However there seems an issue and the workflow is NOT being invoked.

I followed steps from here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Workflows

[image]

But this notify activity or may be even the start activity doesn't seem to be invoked/working . What More settings are required to get this workflow in action ?

Also, I have set the redirect URL in "Forms" element properties but the form isn't redirecting. What can be the issue here as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this problem with a workflow before. I assume there's nothing in the logs?

My first guess would be that it's your form that is not submitting properly, try to remove that redirect, also make sure there's isn't some validation error blocking it, if you placed recaptcha element remove it and try again.

Second guess which is not very likely is that you have somehow managed to hide notification zone, either with CSS or in layout view `@Zone(Model.Messages)`

Comment: There is NO recaptcha element added. Also in Console I see NO errors. Can you please tell what is this Notification Zone ?

Comment: It's the zone where notifications appear so you can control it, are you using default TheThemeMachine theme?

Comment: Yes I am using the default theme. does this got something to do with Workflows ?